# Insert with Select Query on Aggregate Function

Tags: mysql

Referring to following thread:
[Can you use aggregate values within ON DUPLICATE KEY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17837841/can-you-use-aggregate-values-within-on-duplicate-key)

I tried to copy that as well as many other ways to insert a value on ma20 but nothing has worked and I continually get the following error:
**Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'histClose' in 'field list'**

What am I doing wrong and how can I make this work?

```
insert into moving_average (ma_symbol, ma_date, ma20)
select 'A', max(histDate) as maxHistDate, avg(histClose) as histClose
from
   (select histDate, histClose
   from historical_data
   where symbol like 'A'
   order by histDate asc
   limit 20) temp
   on duplicate key update ma20 = values(histClose);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `values` keyword takes the name of the column in the table . . . it is the value that would go into the column:

```
insert into moving_average (ma_symbol, ma_date, ma20)
    select 'A', max(histDate) as maxHistDate, avg(histClose) as histClose
    from (select histDate, histClose
          from historical_data
          where symbol like 'A'
          order by histDate asc
          limit 20
         ) temp
    on duplicate key update ma20 = values(ma20);
```